# Dart programming syntax for every method

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dart

I am trying to convert Javascript function to dart function. So here are some errors I am receiving

```
Error compiling to JavaScript:
main.dart:10:9:
Error: Expected an identifier, but got 'var'.
        var i = y.indexOf(x);
        ^^^
main.dart:10:9:
Error: Expected '}' before this.
        var i = y.indexOf(x);
        ^^^
Error: Compilation failed.
```

I am unable to understand what is wrong with the syntax. If you help me with every method, I might be able to understand the rest of the dart methods too.

Here is the code:

```
void main() {
   print(commonChars(["bella","label","roller"]));
}

commonChars(array){
  var arr = array.map((x) => [...x]);
  var firstObject = arr.shift();
  return firstObject.filter((x) => 
    arr.every((y) => {
        var i = y.indexOf(x);
        if (i >= 0) {
          return (y[i] = true);
        }
    })                          
  );  
}
```

The result of this code should be ["e","l","l"]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You own example are failing primary of missing types (e.g. you are missing return type of the method).

It is difficult to directly translate the JavaScript code to Dart since letters in Dart are not easily iterated. But I have rewritten your code into this which should work:

```
void main() {
  print(commonChars(["bella", "label", "roller"])); // [e, l, l]
}

List<String> commonChars(List<String> arrays) {
  final firstString = arrays.first;
  final result = <String>[];

  for (var i = 0; i < firstString.length; i++) {
    final letter = firstString[i];

    if (arrays.skip(1).every((string) => string.contains(letter))) {
      result.add(letter);
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

And if you want to make it really compact you can do something like this:

```
void main() {
  print(commonChars(["bella", "label", "roller"])); // [e, l, l]
}

List<String> commonChars(List<String> arrays) => [
      for (var i = 0; i < arrays.first.length; i++)
        if (arrays.skip(1).every((string) => string.contains(arrays.first[i])))
          arrays.first[i]
    ];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Keep solving questions like this. I love your answer. I am trying to learn dart using javascript too since I am focusing on Flutter and React JS

Comment: Good luck with the adventure. :)